# Where does the maximum voltage come from in a vacuum capacitor?

Tags: capacitance, voltage

If too much voltage is placed across a normal capacitor then the capacitors material in the dielectric will break down and the capacitor will fail, this makes sense to me.

That being said some capacitors are designed to use a high vacuum as a dielectric and yet these capacitors still have maximum safe voltages, albeit much higher than that of a conventional capacitor. what causes a vacuum capacitor to fail at high voltages if not a failure of the dielectric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breakdown is a two step process. When the voltage becomes high enough you get [field emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission) from the surface of the capacitor plates. With perfectly smooth surfaces this is all that happens, but with real surfaces you get points where the emission is enhanced due to surface irregularities. Current flowing at those points causes local heating, which enhances emission and you get a feedback loop resulting in a spark between the surfaces.

Comment: Larger electric field at the edges of the capacitor plates?

Comment: @Farcher I'm assuming the plates are sufficiently large that we can ignore the edges. So the emission hot spots come from microscale irregularities on the plates.

Comment: Surface contamination can play a large role as well (how big a role depends on what one considers 'high' vacuum, of course).